# Get the json path of a value with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to retrieve the json path of a value from a json string with jackson. As I couldn't find any function inside jackson giving me this result, I wanted to create my own function.

So I made this function :

```
public static String getJsonPath(Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> jsonNode, String valueSearched) {
    String res = "";
    String key = jsonNode.getKey();
    JsonNode value = jsonNode.getValue();
    if (value.isValueNode() && value.equals(valueSearched)) { // Here the value change to a ValueNode and the key weirdly equals to "".
        return res + key;
    } else {
        if (value.isContainerNode()) {
            if (value.isObject()) {
                Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> elements = value.fields();
                while (elements.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> element = elements.next();
                    res += "." + element.getKey() + generateJsonPathArgumentFromJson(element, valueSearched);
                }
            } else {
                int i = 0;
                ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) jsonNode;
                Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonNode>> elements = arrayNode.fields();
                while (elements.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> element = elements.next();
                    i++;
                    res += "(" + i + ")" + generateJsonPathArgumentFromJson(element, valueSearched);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Why the key gets equal to "" after the first if ? Or there's a better way to construct a json path for a specific value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the solutions :

```
protected static String generateJsonPathArgumentFromJson(JsonNode jsonNode, String valueSearched) {
    if (jsonNode.isValueNode() && !jsonNode.asText().equals(valueSearched)) {
        return null;
    } else {
        if (jsonNode.isContainerNode()) {
            if (jsonNode.isObject()) {
                Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> elements = jsonNode.fields();
                while (elements.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> element = elements.next();
                    String res =  generateJsonPathArgumentFromJson(element.getValue(), valueSearched);
                    if (res != null) {
                        return "." + element.getKey() + res;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                int i = 0;
                Iterator<JsonNode> elements = jsonNode.elements();
                while (elements.hasNext()) {
                    JsonNode element = elements.next();
                    String res = generateJsonPathArgumentFromJson(element, valueSearched);
                    if (res != null) {
                        return "(" + i + ")" + res;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

I'm sure there's better way to do, but at least it works :)